# What is the simplest way to pipe from a Read to a Write

Tags: rust

I've got two objects.  One implements the `std::io::Read` trait and the other implements the `std::io::Write` trait (e.g., two `std::fs::File` instances).  I'm trying to figure out a simple and efficient way to pipe the data from the `Read` instance into the `Write` instance.

Let me add that I'm fully aware of `std::fs::copy`, but that only applies to files on a file system...these are not that.  I also looked at `std::io::copy`, but it doesn't work with `Read` and `Write` instances.

I know that I can read the contents of the `Read` into a `Vec<u8>` with something like this:

```
let mut data = Vec::new();
file.read_to_end(&mut data);
```

But `read_to_end` fills a `Vec<u8>` but the corresponding function on `Write`, `write_all`, takes a `&[u8]` and I don't see any method on `Vec<u8>` that allows me to create a new array, only a slice of some pre-specified size.

I can imagine several different ways to do this (read/write one byte at a time, read/write chunks).  But I am hoping that there is some function in `std` that does all this (with all the requisite error handling, chunk size management, etc) but if it is there, I haven't been able to find it.

Any suggestions on a simple way to do this?  I am admittedly relatively new to Rust, but believe me when I say I spent quite a bit of time looking for such a thing and couldn't find it.  Yes, I realize in that time I could have implemented but I wanted something that would be efficient and I'm concerned that what I would write wouldn't be optimal.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: "I also looked at `std::io::copy`, but it doesn't work with `Read` and `Write` instances." Huh? The type parameters `R` and `W` have bounds `R: Read` and `W: Write`, so it should work.

Comment: [`std::io::copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/fn.copy.html) should definitely work. Can you make an MCVE?

Comment: You are correct.  I mistakenly read that as meaning that `reader` and `writer` had to have the `Sized` trait.  My apologies, I should not have missed that. :-(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I also looked at `std::io::copy`, but it doesn't work with `Read` and `Write` instances.

It does. Look at the where clause in [its signature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/fn.copy.html):

```
pub fn copy<R: ?Sized, W: ?Sized>(reader: &mut R, writer: &mut W) -> Result<u64> 
where R: Read, W: Write
```

For instance, here I redirect stdin to stdout:

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
  let mut stdin = io::stdin();
  let mut stdout = io::stdout();
  io::copy(&mut stdin,&mut stdout);
}
```

If you are looking for a buffer to write into and read out of, [`BufStream`](http://alexcrichton.com/bufstream/bufstream/struct.BufStream.html) from the `bufstream` crate should be of use.

> I can imagine several different ways to do this (read/write one byte at a time, read/write chunks). But I am hoping that there is some function in std that does all this (with all the requisite error handling, chunk size management, etc) but if it is there, I haven't been able to find it.

That is *exactly* [what `std::io::copy` does](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.8.0/src/std/up/src/libstd/io/util.rs.html#46-61) - it allocates a buffer and then loops between reading into that buffer and writing out from that buffer until there is nothing left to read.

Comment: Thanks.  First off, you are correct, of course.  Also, your answer was useful because it helped me to realize why `std::io::copy` didn't work for me the first time which was that lack of `&mut` in front of the variable.  The error message confused me, but your example helped me understand what it was trying to tell me.  Thanks again.

Comment: Wait, why does `std::io::copy` take reader and writer args as mut in the first place?

Comment: @infogulch because [`read` methods from `Read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html) and [`write` methods from `Write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html) both require `&mut self`. As for the why behind that, I'd say it is safe to say that most implementations of read and write will require some mutation.